# C# API in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code to generate random jokes from an API and I want it to output a joke to a listbox after pressing a button. But I cant put it working... Im kinda new so any hints to help me pls? Thank you! :)

**My code:**

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JokeGEN
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public class Value
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string joke { get; set; }
            public List<string> categories { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
            public Value value { get; set; }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task<string> responseBody = client.GetStringAsync("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random");
            listBox1.Items.Add(responseBody.Result);
            Root jokes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responseBody.Result);
            string joke = jokes.value.joke;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which part doesn't work? does it throw an exception on a particular line? welcome and please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @kshkarin thank you, I will. The program runs and everything but when I click the button it simply does nothing..

Comment: You're calling and async method, `GetStringAsync()`, but you're not awating it. Make your `button2_Click` handler async, then `var json = await client.GetStringAsync(...);` and deserialize `json`-- You probably want to show the value returned in `jokes.value.joke` in your ListBox. If you actually want to show the raw JSON string, use a TextBox/RichTextBox instead.

Comment: Is ResponseBody.result something that can be added to the Items collection of a listbox?

Comment: BTW, trying to use the `.Result` of an async method, in this Platform, is a bad joke :) Well, not just in this Platform. Actually, everywhere. Maybe in a Console app is tolerable. But `GetAwaiter()` is probably better. So, everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: separate your model from how you display your model (your view). Apart from that your code will be better to reuse, it will also be easier to unit test and thus to debug. If later you decide that you want to view your jokes differently, you won't have to change the model.

```
private async Task<string> FetchJokeAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        const string requestUri = "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random";
        string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        return responseBody;
    }
}
```

**About async-await:** Every method that uses async-await, has to be declared `async`. Return `Task` instead of `void`, and `Task<TResult>` instead of `TResults`. There is only one exception: event handlers return `void` instead of `Task`.

`await` inside the async method. The return value of await is the `TResult`. It is convention to append the identifier of the method with async.

By the way, HttpClient implements IDisposable. This means that the designer of the class thought that it holds scarce resources. It is convention not to keep IDisposable object longer alive then needed. You have to weigh the costs of construction against the cost of holding a scarce resource, but since you are doing this as a result to a button click, I guess you won't do this ten times per second. So reconstructing the Client is no problem.

Apparently you want to display the fetched jokes in a ListBox. You need a method for this:

```
private void DisplayJoke(string joke)
{
    this.listBoxJokes.Items.Add(joke);
}
```

Now to fetch the Joke and Display the fetched joke whenever the button is clicked:

```
private async void OnButtonCreateJoke_ClickedAsync(object sender, ...)
{
    string joke = await this.FetchJokeAsync();
    this.DisplayJoke(joke);
}
```

Remember: OnButtonCreateJoke is an async event handler, the return value should be void, not Task.

If this does not work, it will be easy to debug it. First replace the JokeFetcher:

```
private async Task<string> FetchJokeAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // simulate some wait time
    return "This is a Joke";
}
```

What happens? Is the joke displayed correctly, then apparently the problem is in this method. If not displayed correctly: Try to debug DisplayJoke: what happens if you display it in a Text Box?

```
private void DisplayJoke(string joke)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = joke;
}
```

By now you should know whether the problem is in your joke fetching or joke displaying.

### Conclusion

By separating the model (= how to get a joke) from the view (=how to display the joke) it is way easier to understand what happens, to test your code, and thus to debug your code, it is way easier to change the requirements: if you need to display the joke in a TextBox, changes are minimal.